# PHP parsing a complex SOAP response from SIRI API

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am trying to parse this complex SOAP response:
[image]

But I get lost with the namespaces and children methods...any idea how to extract the highlighted data?

I tried this:

`$xml->children( $ns['S'] )->Body->children( $ns['ns7'] )->Answer->children( $ns['ns3'] );`

but it doesn't work

Comment: So you are stuck on how to write code or?

Comment: Kinda, I know how to parse XML responses, but this SOAP response is quite complex and i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a WSDL to PHP generator which will ease you the request construction and response handling. Indeed, you'll handle PHP object with getters/setters which is better in my point of view.

I can only suggest you to try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.